# How to stop log4net printing stack trace

Tags: c#, log4net

I am using log4net for logging and I'm using the following method.

```
Log.Error(Text, e);
```

However, I don't want it to print the exception to the console as it does currently and instead just the text. How would I do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to log into database instead of console? What is your presentation layer - ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web Form?

Answer (score 1):

If by "just the text" you mean "just the contents of the variable named Text" then just use

```
Log.Error(Text);
```

If by "just the text" you mean "just the contents of the variable named Text plus the exception message, but nothing else about the exception," and assuming `e` contains the exception object, then use:

```
Log.Error(Text + " " + e.Message);
```

Comment: I wish to log the exception, I just don't want it to show in the console if that makes sense.

Comment: It does but I can't tell from your code example why the exception is being displayed on the console. Are you rethrowing it after catching it?